# Python XML Parsing

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

*Note: lxml will not run on my system.  I was hoping to find a solution that does not involve lxml.

I have gone through some of the documentation around here already, and am having difficulties getting this to work how I would like to.  I would like to parse some XML file that looks like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>1375</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Key 1</key><integer>1375</integer>
        <key>Key 2</key><string>Some String</string>
        <key>Key 3</key><string>Another string</string>
        <key>Key 4</key><string>Yet another string</string>
        <key>Key 5</key><string>Strings anyone?</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

In the file I am trying to manipulate, there are more 'dict' that follow this one.  I would like to read through the XML and output a text/dat file that would look like this:

1375, "Some String", "Another String", "Yet another string", "Strings anyone?"

...

Eof

** *Originally*, I tried to use lxml, but after many tries to get it working on my system, I moved on to using DOM.  More recently, I tried using Etree to do this task.  Please, for the love of all that is good, would somebody help me along with this?  I am relatively new to Python and would like to learn how this works.  I thank you in advance.

Comment: What OS and version of Python?

Comment: You have the number 1375 twice. Can this be two different numbers? If so, which do you want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) which is included with Python. There is an included  companion C-implemented (i.e. much faster) `xml.etree.cElementTree`. `lxml.etree` offers a superset of the functionality but it's not needed for what you want to do.

The code provided by @Acorn works identically for me (Python 2.7, Windows 7) with each of the following imports:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import lxml.etree as et
...
tree = et.fromstring(xmltext)
...
```

What OS are you using and what installation problems have you had with `lxml`?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Maverick Meerkat Netbook installation...the latest lxml installation attempt included this message in my terminal: Unpacking python-lxml (from .../python-lxml_2.2.6-1_i386.deb) ...
Setting up firmware-b43-installer (4.150.10.5-4) ...
Not supported low-power chip with PCI id 14e4:4315!
Aborting.

Comment: I just tried the new imports with the code and got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/worky.py", line 5, in <module>
    import lxml.etree as et
ImportError: No module named lxml.etree

Comment: (1) About your Ubuntu installation problem: I suggest that you try the lxml mailing list. (2) "No module named lxml.etree" ... that's because it's not installed. Have only one import active at a time; comment out the other two.

Comment: ok, John, that kind of helps, I'm messing around with the code now... I might be able to swing it with this code, although... it's not exactly what I need... if I can get it to work, it IS what I need I guess.  Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 7):

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import csv

xmltext = """
<dicts>
    <key>1375</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Key 1</key><integer>1375</integer>
        <key>Key 2</key><string>Some String</string>
        <key>Key 3</key><string>Another string</string>
        <key>Key 4</key><string>Yet another string</string>
        <key>Key 5</key><string>Strings anyone?</string>
    </dict>
</dicts>
"""

f = open('output.txt', 'w')

writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

tree = et.fromstring(xmltext)

# iterate over the dict elements
for dict_el in tree.iterfind('dict'):
    data = []
    # get the text contents of each non-key element
    for el in dict_el:
        if el.tag == 'string':
            data.append(el.text)
        # if it's an integer element convert to int so csv wont quote it
        elif el.tag == 'integer':
            data.append(int(el.text))
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting so soon.  The problem is, I cannot get lxml to run on my machine.  I have python 2.7 and have made several attempts to get that module installed, but have failed.  I was hoping there was another way that doesn't involve lxml.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu Maverick Meerkat Netbook edition...

Comment: How are you trying to install it? have you tried installing it with PIP?

Comment: Ok, I am installing pip now, I will try to figure out how to use it to install it.  BTW, it's snowing in New York... wth?!  and thanks for the help.

Comment: Once you have it installed, just `pip install lxml`

Comment: Ugh: building 'lxml.etree' extension
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.6
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/lxml
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:239:

src/lxml/etree_defs.h:9: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  Rolling back uninstall of lxml

Comment: I thought lxml was just 2.7, but 2.6 was being used there?!  I have 2.7 installed, and that's the IDLE I have open and am using...

Comment: I think you need to have libxml2 and libxslt installed. Check out these instructions: http://tightwadtechnica.com/?page_id=4163

Comment: wow.  "Not supported low-power chip" and then it aborts when I try to install libxml2 using apt-get

Comment: trying to use PIP now to install those...

Comment: Ok, well... I'm still getting the same errors when trying to install the things needed to install lxml.  This is why I was hoping to find a solution to the XML parsing without using lxml.

Comment: @PleaseHelpTheNewGuy: **I've given you the solution: xml.etree.[c]ElementTree**

Comment: John, I'm sorry for my ignorance, I'm not really sure what you mean by that : oh wait, ok, I'm guessing you mean the line that's almost like that.

Comment: @PleaseHelpTheNewGuy: I meant with or without the "c"

Comment: Ok, this has all been helpful.  I should be able to hack and slash through the rest of what it is I am trying to do.  Thanks so much guys.  I'm still learning Python and this has been good.

Comment: I've changed my example to use xml.etree